# Executing multiple Sparql Queries with QueryExecutionFactory at once

Tags: java, performance, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I have to execute about say 2000 sparql queries at once. I am currently executing the queries one at a time. Each one takes about 0.3s. So, for all of the queries to execute we need about 600s.This is the code I am using for query execution

```
QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query.asQuery());
//query is a ParameterizedSparqlString which returns Query object
ResultSet resultSet = qExec.execSelect();
```

The above code is inside a loop. The loop runs 2000 times and the code executes 2000 times.

So, I want to **reduce the time taken** to run 2000 queries.

I was thinking if I could execute multiple queries at once like batch insertion done to execute multiple sql statements then I could reduce the time taken. Is there any way I can do it?

Or any possible solution to reduce the time would be life saver to me.

Comment: There is no concept of batch processing in SPARQL. You can run all queries in parallel via plain Java threads. `ExecutorService` is the way to go.

Comment: Note, I'm pretty sure that you might geht in trouble when sending too many queries in parallel given that the public DBpedia service is shared medium and flooding it will probably block your IP temporarily - which makes sense, otherwise, bots could bring down the service easily. If you need DBpedia heavily, load it into a local triple store and use this one.

Comment: You may benefit from your own DBpedia mirror in the Cloud ([2016-10 Snapshot, matching `dbpedia.org/sparql`](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ) or [DBpedia-Live, matching `live.dbpedia.org/sparql`](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK)), which you can configure with less restriction on the SPARQL endpoint, query through JDBC and SPASQL (SPARQL-in-SQL), and/or put on a beefier instance type than the public instance.

Comment: @AKSW I used executorservice to rull all queries in java threads. Worked good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked good to me. 
First I created a Callable Class

```
public class SparqlQueryCallable implements Callable<Model> {
    public static final String DBPEDIA_REPO = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    private ParameterizedSparqlString query = new ParameterizedSparqlString();
    @Override
    public Model call() throws Exception {
        QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(DBPEDIA_REPO, this.query.asQuery());
        Model tempConstruct = qExec.execConstruct();
        return tempConstruct;
    }
}
```

Then inside a loop I created all callable objects

```
List<SparqlQueryCallable> callable_list = new ArrayList<SparqlQueryCallable>();
for(ParameterizedSparqlString param_string: param_strings) {
    callable_list.add(new SparqlQueryCallable(param_string));
}
```

Finally executed it

```
List<Future<Model>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callable_list);
```

It reduced the time significantly.